# Grep text between patterns using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to sort data which reside in txt file. The sample data is as follows:

```
======
Jhon 
Doe 
score -
------  
======
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
======
Will 
Marrow 
score - 
------
```

And I need to extract only sections where `score +` is defined. So the result should be

```
======
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
```

Comment: Perhaps writing a perl script is a better bet

Comment: yes probably, if it solve this task

Comment: sed, grep just deals with lines. You want mult-line match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed can do it as follows:

```
sed -n '/^======/{:a;N;/\n------/!ba;/score +/p}' infile 
======
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
```

where `-n` prevents printing, and

```
/^======/ {       # If the pattern space starts with "======"
    :a            # Label to branch to
    N             # Append next line to pattern space
    /\n------/!ba # If we don't match "------", branch to :a
    /score +/p    # If we match "score +", print the pattern space
}
```

Things could be more properly anchored with `/\n------$/`, but there are spaces at the end of the lines, and I'm not sure if those are real or copy-paste artefacts – but this work for the example data.

Comment: Tested, working too! Even more elegant way and i understand its logic. And if i want two matched patterns between === and ---  Example https://gist.github.com/Demontager/947590bdcf28f55b1018 (added age -) ?

Comment: @Demontager Is `age -` always after `score +`?

Comment: any place between ===and----

Comment: You'd have to replace the `score ` line by `/score +/{/age -/p}`.

Comment: I doing something wrong  $ sed -n '/^======/{:a;N;/------/!ba;/score +/{/age -/p}' test1.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'  Could you please show full line.

Comment: @Demontager You're missing a closing brace, as the error message tells you. `sed -n '/^======/{:a;N;/\n------/!ba;/score +/{/age -/p}}'`

Comment: it's fine now. Accepted your answer, it is more flexible for my task, especially with multiple criteria.

Answer (score 2):

I would try this one:

```
$ grep -B3 -A1 "score +" myfile
```

It means... grep three lines **B**efore and one line **A**fter "score +".

Comment: Yeap working, very tiny way. But extract data as expected if quantity of lines are equal in each section. For my example it fit nice.

Answer (score 1):

give this oneliner a try:

```
awk -v RS="==*" -F'\n' '{p=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/score \+/)p=1}p' file
```

with the given data, it outputs:

```
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
```

The idea is, take all lines divided by `====...` as one multiple-line record, and check if the record contains the searching pattern, print it out.

Comment: Awesome, working as expected!  Could you  please also show how to extract data if more patterns defined. E.g.  not only score + but one more, for example: age -   https://gist.github.com/Demontager/947590bdcf28f55b1018 So two patterns shoud much only between ==== and -----

Comment: @Demontager if you want to check A and B, just write the logic in `if(..)`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='=+\n' '/score \+/' file
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
======
Jhon 
Doe 
score -
------  
======
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
======
Will 
Marrow 
score - 
------
```

You can create a toggle type match in awk to print only the section that you wist:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '/^=+/{f=1;s=$0;next} /^score \+/{f=2} f {s=s"\n"$0} /^-+$/ {if(f==2) {print s} f=0}'
======
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use Grep Context Flags

Assuming you have a truly fixed-format file, you can just use *fgrep* (or GNU or BSD *grep* with the speedy `--fixed-strings` flag) along with the the `--before-context` and `--after-context` flags. For example:

```
$ fgrep -A1 -B3 'score +' /tmp/foo 
======
Ann 
Smith 
score + 
------
```

The flags will find your match, and include the three lines before and one line after each match. This gives you the output you're after, but with a lot less complexity than a sed or awk script. YMMV.